# Azure Functions Logger with BeginScope for ApplicationInsights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

We have an Azure Function app that is enabled for HttpLogging to emit the logs to Azure ApplicationInsights using the following code,

```
var host = new HostBuilder()            
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((_, b) =>
        {                
        }, _ => { })
        .ConfigureServices((c, s) =>
        {
            s.AddTransient<HttpLoggingHandler>();
            s.AddHttpClient("WithLogger").AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpLoggingHandler>();

            s.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
            s.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        }
```

Also, we have used the following in our logging handler,

```
      Dictionary<string, object> scope = new();
      scope.TryAdd("url", requestUri);
      scope.TryAdd("headers", requestHeaders);
      using (_logger.BeginScope(scope))
      {
        _logger.LogInformation("***** Request/Response Logging *****");
      }
```

But, in the Azure Application Insights, we could only find '***** Request/Response Logging *****' in the message property and not the information that we added in scope when we used the following query in Application Insights Logs,

```
traces 
| where operation_Name contains "***** Request/Response Logging *****"
```

Any idea what is it that we are missing?